# What is the regex to match an alphanumeric 6 character string?

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I need regex for asp.net application to match an alphanumeric string at least 6 characters long.

Comment: Just for the record: What do you mean by alphanumeric? Only the latin characters `a`–`z`, `A`–`Z`, and the digits `0`–`9`?

Comment: yes, sometimes with some turkish letters like ĞÜŞİÖÇçöişüğ.

Comment: I thing its changing for country to country.

Comment: In that case use the Unicode character property character classes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I’m not familiar with ASP.NET. But the regular expression should look like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

`^` and `$` denote the begin and end of the string respectively; `[a-zA-Z0-9]` describes one single alphanumeric character and `{6,}` allows six or more repetitions.

Comment: Note though that this does not match the letter 'ö', amongst others.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: I guess that is obvious.

Comment: I am confident you were aware of this (especially since you are living in a country where this is an issue, judging from your profile), but I have come across plenty of people that are not; that's why I commented on it.

Comment: I think the pattern you want is more like `^[\pL\pN]{6,}$`.

Comment: How to modify this regex to accommodate at-least one character and at-least one digit with a total length of 11

Answer (score 16):

I would use this:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]{6,}$
```

This matches Unicode letters (`\p{L}`) and numbers (`\p{N}`), so it's not limited to common letters the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 7):

`^\w{6,}$` `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$`

(Depending on the Regex implementation)

Note, that `\w` also matches `_`!

Comment: `a-Z` is not a valid character range.