# Regex for alphanumeric string with at least 1 number and 1 character and a fixed length of 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I need regex to match an alphanumeric string exact 11 characters long but the value must contain at least both 1 character and 1 number.

Used a combination of
[Regex for alphanumeric with at least 1 number and 1 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-for-alphanumeric-with-at-least-1-number-and-1-character][1])

i.e. `/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/`

and [What is the regex to match an alphanumeric 6 character string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658145/what-is-the-regex-to-match-an-alphanumeric-6-character-string][1])

i.e. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$`

by using OR (||) operator like this

```
//regex code
var str = "";
if ($.trim($("input[id$='txtBranchName']").val()) != "")
    str = $.trim($("input[id$='txtBranchName']").val());
var reg_exp = /^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i; // /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11,}$/;//^(\d)(?:\1+)?$/; // new RegExp('([0-9]){6}');
var reg_exp2 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11,11}$/;
if (!reg_exp.test(str) || !reg_exp2.test(str)) {
    $("span[id$='lblError']").css("color", "red");
    $("span[id$='lblError']").html($("span[id$='lbl_PayeeInformation_IFSCNo']").html()).show();
    $("input[id$='txtBranchName']").focus();
    returned = false;
    return false;
}
//end regex code
```

but it would be great if i get it in one regex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to combine both and use [`{11}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for exact 11 characters match.

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$/
```

---

Where :

1. `(?=.*\d)` assert that the position follows a digit at any position(where `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`).
2. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` assert that the position follows an alphabet at any position.
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}` matches only when the length is  11 characters and within the character class.
4. [`^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) are start and end anchors which help to check whole string.